# Rspec: What means a third, fourth, ...index in brackets options

Tags: rspec

I understand that

```
bundle exec rspec ./spec/admin/admin_user_spec.rb[1:1]
```

runs the first examples/groups defined in the first group. But using --bisect sometime I obtain [1:1:x:y], what means x and y?

Answer (score 0):

This means basically the same: take y-th example/group inside x-th group inside 1st group of 1st group.

```
RSpec.describe 'foo' do
  describe 'bar'
    context 'one'
      specify 'true is true' { expect(true).to be(true) }
      context 'two' do
        specify 'false is false' { expect(false).to be(false) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`[1:1:1]` would mean `specify 'true is true'` 
and `[1:1:2]` would mean everything inside `context 'two'`
and `[1:1:2:1` would mean `specify 'false is false'`